# Freebøx Internet box, how to access HDD , root?

Tags: linux

This is a question rather for **french** stack users.

I wonder how I can read my Freebox server HDD (actually it i flash memory), as `root` ?

Or, at least, how I could see Terminal of the box ? (It is `Ubuntu` based, at least `Debian`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (It is `Ubuntu` based, at least `Debian`)

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebox#Technical_features), it's [BusyBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox).

> I wonder how I can read my Freebox server HDD (actually it i flash memory), as `root` ?
>
> Or, at least, how I could see Terminal of the box ?

Based on the content in http://www.f-x.fr/wikini, [it appears you would need to desolder the flash memory](http://www.f-x.fr/wikini/wakka.php?wiki=PenetrationV5).

Comment: Thank you. Why is it better to build on BusyBox rather than a Debian distro ?

Comment: That question would likely be better asked at http://superuser.com/

Comment: Yes, but this is to be marked *off-topic**, too general.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using a V4 version, it seems to be much more simple:

[Pénétrez une FreeBoxPerso V4 avec un simple Trombone](http://www.f-x.fr/wikini/wakka.php?wiki=PenetrationV4)